# How to create-next-app using version 12 instead of version 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to create a nextjs project for a udemy course, but I need it to be nextjs version 12 instead of version 13.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 17):

It's possible to setup `Next.js` version `12` manually:

```bash
# init the package.json
npm init
```

```bash
# intall next dependencies
npm install next@12.3.4 react react-dom
```

```json
// edit your package.json with next scripts
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
  "lint": "next lint"
}
```

```bash
# create the file structure
.
├── package.json
├── pages
│   ├── index.js
```

```js
// init your index.js
import React from "react";

function index() {
  return <div>Hello world</div>;
}

export default index;
```

```bash
# start next
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the following commands (taken from [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35794#discussioncomment-5328698)), replacing `<app-name>` with your actual app:

```bash
npx create-next-app@12 <app-name> && cd <app-name> && npm i next@12
```

Comment: When I run the comman "npx create-next-app@12.3.4 test" it downloads  
    "next": "13.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: @C.Aglar you didn't run the other 2 commands - in your case `cd test && npm i next@12.3.4`. You need all 3 commands, not just the first one.

Comment: You should run `npm i next@12 react@17 react-dom@17 eslint-config-next@12` according to [next's doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-12)

Comment: I am working with an AI model that is trained through April 2023, so needed to run: `npx create-next-app@12 my-app && cd my-app && npm i next@12.1.6` in order to work with the specific version I needed.

Answer (score 0):

npx create-next-app@12 .
for now is the only solution but indirectly it already uses YARN under the hood

Comment: How is this different from sashoalm's answer?

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76337113/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).