# How to create next js with the version 12

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend

I am going to follow a new course in udemy and it is about creating a website with react. https://www.udemy.com/course/build-the-best-ecommerce-website-ever-with-react-js-next-js/ that is the course. The problem is, instructor is using Next.js version 12 and when I create a next.js now it will create with 13.1 version but there is drastic differences. How can I overcome this ? and is it possible to use yarn while doing it from terminal.

Comment: You can try ```yarn create next-app@12.2.3``` and yes you can use Yarn in the terminal anywhere if you have installed Yarn globally

Comment: can i use npm ?

Comment: yes, the npm equivalent is `npx create-react-app@12.2.3` Note the difference between yarn and npm where in yarn theres no "-" character between create and next-app and in npm there is

Comment: it does not working still with v13

Comment: my bad, i made a typo, it is `npx create-next-app@12.2.3`

Comment: Yes , That's what i made npx create-next-app@12.2.3 but still 13

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470715/13817314 u can try this then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create-next-app using version 12 instead of version 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470624/how-to-create-next-app-using-version-12-instead-of-version-13)