# "npx create-next-app@12 my-app" creates a nextjs project with "next" version 13, why is this?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, npx

When creating nextjs project with `npx create-next-app@12 my-app` I am expecting a nextjs project with a "next" version 12  should be created, however  the nextjs project is instead created with the latest "next" version 13.

It is possible to manually change the version in the dependency list and the do `npm install`. I am wondering if it is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: This question had a -1 vote, but I just attempted something similar.  I ran npx create-react-app@12 and it installed NextJS 14 instead of 12.  I re-ran using `npx create-next-app myapp && cd myapp && npm i -S next@12.1.6` and the project  structure is based on a 14 app (no pages directory).  I think there is some myopia around this, as people are still watching videos and tutorials that require specific versions of NextJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [sashoalm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492336/sashoalm)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76281471/21854834).
I think it'll be helpful if you follow the link to the github and continue reading there.

Comment: Please upvote @LordLoss and follow the link to upvote the answer for @sashoalm, but am working with an AI model that is trained through April 2023, so needed to run: `npx create-next-app@12 my-app && cd my-app && npm i next@12.1.6` in order to work with a specific version.