# NextJS Version does not match after executing npx create-next-app

Tags: next.js

I need to clarify this. I was executing the `npx create-next-app@12.3.4` command from windows console (command line). I am expecting to have the NextJs version 12.3.4 in the app after the process is done. But when it does, when I open the **package.json** file, this is what I have got:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.0.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
```

Which is mean the NextJs I have got in the package is version 14.0.2. Does anybody know how to create the app with the exactly NestJs version I want?

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470624/how-to-create-next-app-using-version-12-instead-of-version-13.

Comment: @AWebb thank you. So from the link you gave, I guess the conclution is "create-next-app" will not give me the specific version. And I have to edited afterwards to get the specific version I want.

Comment: Yes, create-next-app just sets up your project structure and then you need to  specify which version of Next.js you want to use.